# How to add ACF PRO image src="" & alt="" in echo for product category

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, product, archive

I'm struggling to add ACF PRO get_field for image in echo for product categories to display in Archive-product.php

```
<?php
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = true ;
$cat_args = array(
'orderby'    => $orderby,
'order'      => $order,
'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_category', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="row">';
foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
    $image = get_field('product_category' . $term_id );
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
    echo $category->name;
    echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
else {
// no posts found
echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
}
?>
```

Does anyone know about this?

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: taxonomy=product_category&tag_ID=6&post_type=product that where the image from product category.

Comment: `get_field('product_category' . $term_id );` to `get_field('product_category' , $term_id );` (the comma). If not, try this guide: https://wpza.net/woocommerce/how-to-get-custom-fields-of-woocommerce-attributes/

Comment: @WPZA thanks , it works also how do I add placeholder image in img src if no image in category?

Comment: Use `if ( ! $thumbnail_image ) {$thumbnail_image = get_field( 'default_image', 'option'; }` using your options page: https://wpza.net/advanced-custom-fields/how-to-add-an-options-page-in-acf/

Comment: @WPZA, I mean like `$feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID(),'catimages') );
                if($feat_image_url == '')
{ 
$feat_image_url = 'https://www.mirius.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/placeholder.png';

}` I got this from Google but I copy it and there is no placeholder image.

Comment: @WPZA like this one see screenshot http://bubblei.co.uk/MXmGqI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE: How do placeholder image in img src if no image in category?

This works for me:

```
<?php

$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = true ;
$cat_args = array(
'orderby'    => $orderby,
'order'      => $order,
'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_category', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        $image = get_field('product_category', $category );
        if($image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/placeholder.png">';
        }
        echo '</a>';
        echo $category->description;
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
else {
    // no posts found
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
}
?>
```